# computed property not defined although it is... defined - vue.js

Tags: vue.js

I am working with my new project with Vue.js and such an error has been showed to me:

> [Vue warn]: Property or method "myImage" is not defined on the
>   instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is
>   reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by
>   initializing the property.

Here is the code:

```
<template>
          <div class="selectedPlayer"><div class="avatar" v-bind:style="myImage"></div>
          <div class="playerName">{{ playerName }}</div>
        </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  name: 'messageForPlayer',
  props: [ "playerId", "playerName" ],
  data () {
    return {
//        myImage: "background-image: url(/src/img/uploads/101.jpg)",
    }

  },
  computed: {
    myImage: function () {
      return {
        'background-image': "url(/src/img/uploads/101.jpg)"
      }
    }
  }} 
</script>
```

As you can see there is computed property called "myImage" with hardcoded value (just for tests, normally it will come from props) but it causes an error. If i unhash "myImage" in data - it works all good, but this value myst by dynamic.
What am i doing wrong?

Kalreg

Comment: Did you copy your code right? Your last line says  `}}, </script> `, the `,` should break Vue and make compiling impossible.

Comment: Code is fine, but it is just a little bit larger, sso i didnt copied it all

Comment: I can't recreate your error, see this sandbox:  https://codesandbox.io/s/31y9jo58p5  
The error has to come from somewhere else, please provide the full code.

Comment: i did find it - i had computed object twice. First was creating my methods, and second was clearing it. Feel like most stupid person in the world now :D

Comment: Fine, that's why you always post the whole related code block when asking for help.

Comment: there was so many lines of code thhat seemed not useful that i ommited it. Anyways trying to make fiddle showed me the reason. thanks!